# Running Gulp in Docker - not found

Tags: docker, gulp, docker-compose

I'm trying to create a `docker-compose` setup of NodeJs, Alpine, MongoDB and gulp to run typescript but I'm struggling to get gulp to run.

When running `docker-compose build`, I get the following:

```
node1_1 /bin/sh: [gulp]: not found
```

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: '3'
services:
 node1:
 build: ./node1
 ports: 
  - "3031:3031"
volumes:
  - .:/src
links: 
  - mongo
mongo:
 image: mongo
 ports: 
  - "27018:27017"
 volumes:
  - /data/mongodb/db:/data/db
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:8.0-alpine
RUN mkdir -p /src
WORKDIR /src
ADD . /src

RUN apk update && apk upgrade

COPY package.json .
RUN npm install --quiet
RUN npm install gulp-cli -g 
RUN npm install gulp -D
RUN npm i gulp

EXPOSE 3031
VOLUME ["/src"]
CMD ['gulp']
```

Please, can someone suggest a solution?

Comment: did you check the `gulpfile.js` is available in root of the folder

Comment: @Kasiriveni thank you for your reply, it's in same directory as the dockerfile and i have tried running `COPY gulpfile.js .` to copy it into the src volume

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the link of the alpine OS commands, if you change this line of the dockerfile, it should work.

```
CMD gulp
```

Comment: unfortunately this does not make a difference

Comment: things are looking better it now says `Local gulp not found in /src.  Try running npm install gulp`

Comment: I recommend you delete the volume, Because you are erasing with your file system